# How to get Oracle Server Version using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement in which I need to check whether oracle server installed and if installed, I need to find out the version also using Powershell. I got the below command

```
$OracleInstalled = get-wmiobject -Class win32_service | ?{$_.name -like '*ORACLESERV*' }
```

But not sure this is correct or not. This only checks for the service I feel.

Anyone aware of this kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

It gives:

ExitCode  : 0

Name      : OracleServiceORCL

ProcessId : 1980

StartMode : Auto
State     : Running

Status    : OK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).